# Error for NIMutableTableViewModel `AnyClass does not conform to NITableViewModelDelegate`

Tags: ios, swift, nimbus, nimbus-ios

In ObjC the code would be like

```
self.tableModel = [[NIMutableTableViewModel alloc] initWithDelegate:(id)[NICellFactory class]];
```

In Swift

```
 self.tableModel = NIMutableTableViewModel(delegate:NICellFactory.classForCoder())
```

In Swift, It gives me error `AnyClass does not conform to NITableViewModelDelegate` . In fact the class NICellFactory doesn't and can't conform to the protocol NITableViewModelDelegate Explicitly.

Is there an alternate way ?

Answer (score 0):

Guys who want the solution can see this issue details https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/issues/577

And this is swift port
https://github.com/NimbusKit/swift

Relevant code here:
[TableCellFactory.swift](https://github.com/NimbusKit/swift/blob/master/TableCellFactory.swift)